# Replace the params in the Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, rackup

I have a app in rails 2.3 and want to have a middleware which can replace the entire params hash with a new hash

i would be having the rack request object in my middleware so when i do request.params it returns me some hash say `{"y" => "c", "x" => "4"}` now my requirement is i want to delete everything and create a request.params object as `{"z" => "t"}` i just want to replace the hash i don't see any setter method available to replace the hash is there any way to do this?

Comment: Someone might be interested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282972/alter-rails-params-hash-from-rack-middleware?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
request.params.clear
request.params[:new] = "hi"
p request.params
```

Comment: that works like a gem thanks this is what i was expecting