# Alter Rails params hash from Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am attempting to add a value to the Rails params hash from a custom Rack middleware object. My current approach is using

```
class PortalResolver

 def initialize(app)
   @app = app
 end

  def call(env)
    begin
      url = "#{env['rack.url_scheme']}://#{env['HTTP_HOST']}"
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      portal_id = DomainService.domain(url) # DomainService is returning the expected value
      request.params['portal_id'] = portal_id
      status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
      [status, headers, response]
    rescue PortalNotFoundError => e
      [403, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['']]
    end
  end
end
```

I'm currently adding the middleware after ActionDispatch::ParamsParser. The parameters don't show up in the Rails params hash from a controller, but do show up in the request.params hash (within the middleware object defined above.) Any ideas? Help much appreciated.

Comment: so you are creating a `request` object but then you don't do anything with it? how is that supposed to show up in the controller?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [docs for `Rack::Request#params`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#params-instance_method) say:

> Note that modifications will not be persisted in the env. Use [update_param](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Request.html#method-i-update_param) or [delete_param](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Request.html#method-i-delete_param) if you want to destructively modify params.

When you use the line

```
request.params['portal_id'] = portal_id
```

you add the new parameter to the hash created for that instance of Rack::Request, but the `env` that is passed on to rails isn’t modified. To make the new value available further down the Rack stack use `update_param` as the docs suggest:

```
request.update_param('portal_id', portal_id)
```

Comment: That was it! Definitely reinforces the importance of closely reading the docs.